# how to set focus in previous row control when press up arrow from keyboard

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, telerik, rad-controls

I am using Telerik RadGrid and i have 3 colums with edit mode so i want to move my cursor by pressing navigation keys in key board, so i need how to set focus in previous or next row control when press navigation keys from keyboard and same for left and right for move left and right.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can press shift+tab to get back.

Comment: it is working properly but when i am at last control when i try to focus on previous row last column i have to press shift tab multipule time so i required that